# Deallocating memory of object inside a pair of a vector

Tags: c++, iterator, delete-operator, std-pair

I would like to know how to de-allocate memory of an object inside a pair of a vector.

```
vector< pair<int, object*> > vectorObject;
```

I did try using an iterator to iterate through all the elements, but I am unsure of how to delete an object that is inside a pair.

```
for (vector< pair<int, object*> >::iterator it = vectorObject.begin(); it != vectorObject.end(); ++it) {
    // delete?
}
```

Hopefully someone will be kind enough to advise!

Comment: `delete it->second;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The straight answer is:

```
for (vector< pair<int, object*> >::iterator it = vectorObject.begin(); it != vectorObject.end(); ++it) {
    delete it->second;
}
```

But. You should probably not be doing this.
Having unmanged pointers is a BAD idea. You should change the type of the vector to use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
vector< pair<int, std::unique_ptr<object>>>  vectorObject;
```

This is because manually deleting objects is error prone and unless you take safeguards (by uisng RAII) **NOT exception safe**.

Comment: I'm currently not using C++11. Is there no other safer ways of deallocating object memory?

Comment: Alternatively you can use boost::shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
for (vector< pair<int, object*> >::iterator it = vectorObject.begin(); it != vectorObject.end(); ++it) {
    delete it->second;
}
```

Or dereference the iterator and delete the second:

```
typedef pair<int, object*> mypair;

for (vector< mypair >::iterator it = vectorObject.begin(); it != vectorObject.end(); ++it) {
    mypair &current = *it;
    delete current.second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the range-based for loop in C++11:

```
for (const auto& pair : vectorObject)
    delete pair.second;
```

And since we're already talking about C++11, you might as well change your container to:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<object>>> vectorObject;
```

Always prefer smart pointers to handle object ownership in C++11.